# How to interpret the result of pandas dataframe boolean index

Tags: pandas

The above operation seems a little trivia, however, I am a little lost as to the output of the operation. Below is a piece of code to illustrate my point.

```
    # sample data for understanding concept of boolean indexing:
    d_f = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'y':[10,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,5]})

    # changing index of dataframe:
    d_f = d_f.set_index([list('abcdefghig')])

    # a list of data:
    myL = np.array(range(1,11))

    # loop through data to boolean slicing and indexing:
    for r in myL:
         DF2 = d_f['x'].values == r
```

The result of the above code is:

```
    array([False,
           False,
           False,
           False,
           False,
           False,
           False,
           False,
           False,
           False],
           dtype=bool
```

But all the values in **myL** are in **d_f['x']**.values except **0**. It, therefore, appears that the program was doing an 'index for index' matching of the elements in the **myL** and **d_f['x']**.values. Is this a typical behavior of pandas library? If so, can some please explain the rationale behind this for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "But all the values in 'myL' are in d_f['x'].values except '0'"... no, except for 10, which is the last value checked, so of course DF2 is all False (the last result overwrites all the previous).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @coldspeed states, you are overwriting DF2 with `d_f['x'] == 10` which is a boolean series of all False.

What I think you are trying to do is this instead:

```
d_f['x'].isin(myL)
```

Output:

```
a    False
b     True
c     True
d     True
e     True
f     True
g     True
h     True
i     True
g     True
Name: x, dtype: bool
```